# Scaling a sequence in F#

Tags: f#, sequences

I am trying to scale a sequence by the first element of the sequence, so the first element will always be one, and then subsequent elements are a ratio of the first element to the nth element of the original sequence.

Here is my code,

```
       open System
       open System.Collections

           let squish1 (x:Double seq) =
                let r =  (Seq.head x:Double)
                Seq.fold (fun (xi:Double) (r:Double) -> xi/r);;
```

And I test on this little vector:-

```
                squish1 [|5.0; 1.0; 1.0; 1.0; 1.0; 1.0|];;
```

I have typed everything because I get this error message

> normaliseSequence.fsx(9,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been >inferred to have generic type
>      val it : (Double -> '_a -> Double) when '_a :> seq
>   Either make the arguments to 'it' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, >add a type annotation.

But clearly I am misunderstanding because I get the error message even with everything typed. What am I missing?

Any and all advice gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: Note that it is more idiomatic in F# to use the alias `float` rather than `System.Double`.

Comment: Yes I know. This was a design choice by our development team, due to the types of data we sometimes have to handle.

Comment: But `float` is simply an alias for `System.Double`. They're the same thing. kvb is just saying that it's more idiomatic to use the `float` alias in your code - it changes nothing about the behavior of your program.

Comment: Interesting, will pass your comments on to the lead developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fold` expects two more parameters, the seed value and the sequence. This works:

```
let squish1 (x:Double seq) =
    let r =  (Seq.head x:Double)
    Seq.fold (fun (xi:Double) (r:Double) -> xi/r) 0.0 x
```

However, I'm guessing you probably want `map` instead of `fold`:

```
let squish1 (x:Double seq) =
    let r =  (Seq.head x:Double)
    Seq.map (fun (xi:Double) -> xi/r) x
```

Incidentally, I would probably write it this way:

```
let inline squish1 (x:seq<_>) =
  let r = Seq.head x
  Seq.map (fun n -> n / r) x
```

Now it works for all types that support  division.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am now just getting 0.0 as the answer! I was hoping for a scaled sequence? Am I using the wrong function (.fold)?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right now. I have got rid of |> Seq.skip 1
as that meant that the first term was missed off, but that is working as expected now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Oh, just saw the revised version. That's very neat.

Comment: Ha ha it is now dividing r by the terms of x, so it is giving the inverse of the answers I want!

Comment: Oops, you're right. You'll have to use `Seq.map (fun n -> n / r) x`

Comment: Thanks. Above and beyond the call of duty there :)